# Anyone know how to set group volume in soco (python)?

Tags: python, sonos

I am trying to set group volume in soco (python) for my Sonos speakers. It is straightforward to set individual speaker volume but I have not found any way to set volume on group level (without iterating through each speaker setting the volume individually). Any idea to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily iterate over the group, and change all their volumes, for example to increate the volume on all speakers by 5:

for each_speaker in my_zone.group:
  each_speaker.volume += 5

(assuming my_zone is you speaker object)